# avoid duplicating code by re-structuring if statement/do loop

Tags: performance, if-statement, fortran

Hi I am trying to impose a specific condition on my function at many different spatial points in my grid.  However I am duplicating lots of code and it's becoming increasingly inefficient.

How can I do what I need to by simply using a do loop?  The specific condition I am trying to impose on my function is the same at all the different spatial points so I figure theres a way to do all of this in a single loop.  Or how can I combine all these If/else if statements into a single statement?  There must be a more efficient way than what I am doing.

I provided a sample code below.

```
FUNCTION grad(psi)
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER :: i,j,kk,ll
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: nx = 24, ny = 24
COMPLEX,DIMENSION(3,3,-nx:nx, -ny:ny) :: psi, grad
REAL :: pi
REAL :: f0
INTEGER :: nxx, nyy

nxx = nx/2
nyy = ny/2

pi = 4*atan(1.0)
f0 = pi**2*1.3

DO i=-nx+1,nx-1 !spatial points
DO j=-ny+1,ny-1 !spatial points

   IF ( i == 0 .AND. j == 0 .AND. i == j) THEN ! I have lots of statements like this

    DO kk=1,3

         grad(kk,1,i,j)  = psi(kk,1,i+1,j) - f0*psi(kk,1,i,j)

         grad(kk,2,i,j)  = psi(kk,2,i+1,j) - f0*psi(kk,2,i,j)

         grad(kk,3,i,j)  = psi(kk,3,i+1,j) - f0*psi(kk,3,i,j)

    END DO

    ELSE IF ( i == nxx .AND. j == nyy .AND. i == j) THEN ! I have lots of statements like this

    DO kk=1,3

         grad(kk,1,i,j)  = psi(kk,1,i+1,j) - f0*psi(kk,1,i,j)

         grad(kk,2,i,j)  = psi(kk,2,i+1,j) - f0*psi(kk,2,i,j)

         grad(kk,3,i,j)  = psi(kk,3,i+1,j) - f0*psi(kk,3,i,j)

    END DO

  ELSE IF ( i == -nxx .AND. j == -nyy .AND. i == j) THEN ! I have lots of statements like this

    DO kk=1,3

         grad(kk,1,i,j)  = psi(kk,1,i+1,j) - f0*psi(kk,1,i,j)

         grad(kk,2,i,j)  = psi(kk,2,i+1,j) - f0*psi(kk,2,i,j)

         grad(kk,3,i,j)  = psi(kk,3,i+1,j) - f0*psi(kk,3,i,j)

    END DO

   ELSE IF ( i == nxx .AND. j == -nyy) THEN ! I have lots of statements like this

    DO kk=1,3

         grad(kk,1,i,j)  = psi(kk,1,i+1,j) - f0*psi(kk,1,i,j)

         grad(kk,2,i,j)  = psi(kk,2,i+1,j) - f0*psi(kk,2,i,j)

         grad(kk,3,i,j)  = psi(kk,3,i+1,j) - f0*psi(kk,3,i,j)

    END DO

   ELSE IF ( i == -nxx .AND. j == nyy) THEN

    DO kk=1,3

         grad(kk,1,i,j)  = psi(kk,1,i+1,j) - f0*psi(kk,1,i,j)

         grad(kk,2,i,j)  = psi(kk,2,i+1,j) - f0*psi(kk,2,i,j)

         grad(kk,3,i,j)  = psi(kk,3,i+1,j) - f0*psi(kk,3,i,j)

    END DO

  ELSE IF ( i == nxx .AND. j == ny) THEN

    DO kk=1,3

         grad(kk,1,i,j)  = psi(kk,1,i+1,j) - f0*psi(kk,1,i,j)

         grad(kk,2,i,j)  = psi(kk,2,i+1,j) - f0*psi(kk,2,i,j)

         grad(kk,3,i,j)  = psi(kk,3,i+1,j) - f0*psi(kk,3,i,j)

    END DO

  ELSE IF ( i == -nxx .AND. j == ny) THEN

    DO kk=1,3

         grad(kk,1,i,j)  = psi(kk,1,i+1,j) - f0*psi(kk,1,i,j)

         grad(kk,2,i,j)  = psi(kk,2,i+1,j) - f0*psi(kk,2,i,j)

         grad(kk,3,i,j)  = psi(kk,3,i+1,j) - f0*psi(kk,3,i,j)

    END DO

   ELSE IF ( i == nx .AND. j == -nyy) THEN

    DO kk=1,3

         grad(kk,1,i,j)  = psi(kk,1,i+1,j) - f0*psi(kk,1,i,j)

         grad(kk,2,i,j)  = psi(kk,2,i+1,j) - f0*psi(kk,2,i,j)

         grad(kk,3,i,j)  = psi(kk,3,i+1,j) - f0*psi(kk,3,i,j)

    END DO

   ELSE IF ( i == nx .AND. j == nyy) THEN

    DO kk=1,3

         grad(kk,1,i,j)  = psi(kk,1,i+1,j) - f0*psi(kk,1,i,j)

         grad(kk,2,i,j)  = psi(kk,2,i+1,j) - f0*psi(kk,2,i,j)

         grad(kk,3,i,j)  = psi(kk,3,i+1,j) - f0*psi(kk,3,i,j)

    END DO

    ELSE 

        DO kk=1,3

        grad(kk,1,i,j)  = psi(kk,1,i+1,j) 

        grad(kk,2,i,j)  = psi(kk,2,i+1,j)

        grad(kk,3,i,j)  = psi(kk,3,i+1,j)

    END DO

   END IF

END DO
END DO

END FUNCTION grad
```

Comment: Three simple ideas that come to mind are use .Or., use an include file or call (a probably internal) subroutine. Array syntax would simplify it as well. But I probably wouldn't start from here - I would set the whole grid "default" value and then use separate loops to modify the exceptional values, not an if in sight.

Comment: @IanBush Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for *conciseness*, I'd say you can be much, much more concise than you are. The whole function you provided can be rewritten just like this:

```
function grad(psi)
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: nx = 24, ny = 24, nxx = nx / 2, nyy = ny / 2
  real, parameter :: pi = 4 * atan(1.0), f0 = pi ** 2 * 1.3
  complex, dimension(3,3,-nx:nx,-ny:ny) :: psi, grad

  grad(:,:,-nx+1:nx-1,-ny+1:ny-1) = psi(:,:,-nx+2:nx,-ny+1:ny-1)
  grad(:,:,0,0) = psi(:,:,1,0)
  grad(:,:,[-nxx,nxx],[-nyy,nyy,ny]) = psi(:,:,[-nxx+1,nxx+1],[-nyy,nyy,ny]) - f0 * psi(:,:,[-nxx,nxx],[-nyy,nyy,ny])
  !grad(:,:,nx,[-nyy,nyy]) = psi(:,:,nx+1,[-nyy,nyy]) - f0 * psi(:,:,nx,[-nyy,nyy])
end
```

As said by @IanBush, assigning the default values then modifying the special cases seems a good aproach. Also, [array sections notation](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/561/Syllabus/6-Fortran/array4.html) is one of the distinctive and powerful features of Fortran language, and can be used to increase expressiveness without compromising clarity.

Pure colons mean *all values in this dimension*, and a colon between values means *only values within this range in this dimension*.

So, when I write `grad(:,:,-nx+1:nx-1,-ny+1:ny-1) = psi(:,:,-nx+2:nx,-ny+1:ny-1)` I mean: *i'm assigning values from the array `psi` to `grad`; I include all values from the two first dimensions, but only a subset of the two last dimensions (I'm excluding the fisrt and last in each); also, they are mapped directly except for the third dimension, that maps to the next of the equivalent position in `psi`*.

When I write `grad(:,:,[-nxx,nxx],[-nyy,nyy,ny])`, I am specifying a list of indices instead of a range for the third and fourth dimensions. This will include the total combinations of the two lists: `-nxx,-nyy`, `-nxx,nyy`, `-nxx,ny`, `nxx,-nyy`...

One advantage of this notation is that, as it is more obvious and closer to the mathematical notation, it is easier to catch inconsistencies. That is why the last line is commented out: an index `nx+1`, as you would have in the 8th and 9th conditions in the code you wrote, would be out of bounds. I don't know if the sample code you presented is official; if it is, you should correct your algorithm (well, as you are looping only from the second to the second-last indices, you'd actually never touch those conditions...).

As an additional advice, you could put your custom functions in a module, so you could pass all those parameter declarations to the module scope. Moreover, you could then consider assumed-shape array arguments.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  As you've noticed, I'm not so familiar or comfortable with the colon notation.  I need to think a bit about your answer and implement it, I'll likely have a few questions as I go through all of this. Thanks a lot for the clear concise answer.

Comment: I just posted a new question that is an extension of this problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53598732/improving-efficiency-of-code-by-correctly-defining-a-list-of-indices. I am trying to modify my code even more now since my list of indices is much bigger than this example.  If you have any solution to it, thank you so much!  This solution greatly helped me as is, and you're really helping me improve the efficiency of my code.