# Improving efficiency of code by correctly defining a list of indices

Tags: fortran

I asked this question [avoid duplicating code by re-structuring if statement/do loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289143/avoid-duplicating-code-by-re-structuring-if-statement-do-loop) in order to determine how I could make my code more efficient.  The solution greatly helped me and is shown below.

```
function grad(psi)
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: nx = 24, ny = 24, nxx = nx / 2, nyy = ny / 2
  real, parameter :: pi = 4 * atan(1.0), f0 = pi ** 2 * 1.3
  complex, dimension(3,3,-nx:nx,-ny:ny) :: psi, grad

  grad(:,:,-nx+1:nx-1,-ny+1:ny-1) = psi(:,:,-nx+2:nx,-ny+1:ny-1)
  grad(:,:,0,0) = psi(:,:,1,0)
  grad(:,:,[-nxx,nxx],[-nyy,nyy,ny]) = psi(:,:,[-nxx+1,nxx+1],[-nyy,nyy,ny]) - f0 * psi(:,:,[-nxx,nxx],[-nyy,nyy,ny])

end
```

However I need to optimize my code even more now.

In the example above there is a portion given by

```
grad(:,:,[-nxx,nxx],[-nyy,nyy,ny]) = psi(:,:,[-nxx+1,nxx+1],[-nyy,nyy,ny]) - ...
```

which effectively does what I need by taking into account all the combinations of the lists `-nxx,-nyy, -nxx, nyy,` etc.

However the list of indices I need is much bigger than just `[-nxx,nxx],[-nyy,nyy]`.  I really need something like `[-nxx,nxx,-nxx1,nxx1,-nxx2,nxx2,-nxx3,nxx3], [-nyy,nyy,-nyy1,nyy1,-nyy2,nyy2,-nyy3,nyy3]` etc where `nxx = nx/2, nxx1 = nx/4, nxx2 = nx/8, nxx3 = nx/16` etc.

Is there a way I can do this efficiently?  For example, can I just define a single variable such as :

```
integer : Listx, Listy

   Listx = [-nxx,nxx,-nxx1,nxx1,-nxx2,nxx2,-nxx3,nxx3]
   Listy = [-nyy,nyy,-nyy1,nyy1,-nyy2,nyy2,-nyy3,nyy3]
```

and then have something like

```
grad(:,:,Listx,Listy) = psi(:,:,Listx+1,Listy) - ...
```

I did try doing this, but defining Listx, Listy as integers seems to be giving problems.   I tried as follows:

```
Integer :: Listx, Listy

   Listx = [-nxx,nxx,-nxx1,nxx1,-nxx2,nxx2,-nxx3,nxx3]
   Listy = [-nyy,nyy,-nyy1,nyy1,-nyy2,nyy2,-nyy3,nyy3]
```

but then upon compiling Fortran tells me that "Incompatible ranks 0 and in assignment at ..."

How can I correctly define this?  Thanks

Comment: What errors did you get? Can you share how exactly you declare those variables? If Listx and Listy are going to be arrays, don't forget to declare a dimension attribute, like `integer :: Listx(8)`

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues The error I got was "Incompatible ranks 0 and in assignment at ..." However, I didnt know to define them as arrays as you just suggested...I used `integer :: Listx` instead of `integer :: Listx(8)`.  Thanks a lot.  So I just needed to add in the dimension attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments, you are missing the `dimension` attribute in the declaration of the arrays:

```
Integer :: Listx(8), Listy(8)
```

This should solve your problem. Any expression that results to a rank-1 array is allowed as a vector subscript indexer.